# a4j:status hide status is not working

Tags: jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf

In my project I am using RichFaces.

When I click on the `a4j:commandButton` button, which is used for saving the page as a pdf, a4j:status is shown on the page and then pdf window opens with Cancel and Ok buttons. I proceed to click on the Ok button.

After that the Ajax loader is still shown. It does not hide even though the page is getting refreshed manually.

Here is my code:

```
<a4j:commandButton id="pdfButton" status="ajaxStatus"
                   image="#GeneralPageAttributes.pdfImage}"
                   title="#{platform.clickToPdfLabel}" 
                   alt="ExportPDF" 
                   onclick="selectedText(#{fileContentDiv})"
                   action="#{FileViewer.pdfBeforePerformAction}"  
                   reRender="bottomOutputPanelId"/>  

<a4j:status id="ajaxStatus" onstart="#{rich:component('fileViewerProgressModalPanel')}.show();"
            onstop="#{rich:component('fileViewerProgressModalPanel')}.hide();" />


<rich:modalPanel id="fileViewerProgressModalPanel"
                 shadowOpacity="0"
                 autosized="true"
                 style="background:none;border:none;"
                 moveable="true">
                 <h:graphicImage url="#{GeneralPageAttributes.progressBarImage}"/>    
</rich:modalPanel>
```

Any idea how to hide the a4j:status after pdf window is closed?

Answer (score 1):

Change the `id` attribute of the `a4j:status` to a `name` attribute with the same value.

One of the numerous meaningless and incompatible changes made between RichFaces 3 and 4, most of them undocumented, was to change the hook between `status=` and `a4j:status` from the `id` attribute to the `name` attribute.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31064946/207421) for a long list.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the attribute name="ajaxStatus" to a4j:status:

```
<a4j:status id="ajaxStatus" name="ajaxStatus" onstart="#{rich:component('fileViewerProgressModalPanel')}.show();"
        onstop="#{rich:component('fileViewerProgressModalPanel')}.hide();" />
```