# jsf difference between true and #{true} in condition check

Tags: jsf

for any condition check in JSF, what make difference between `"true"` and `#{true}`.

How this effect jsf condition.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't in JSF, but there are parts of other (poorly written) JSF-based layers like RichFaces that will understand `"#{true}"` but not `"true"`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12585086/richfaces-3-to-richfaces-4-migration/31064946?s=1|6.1889#31064946) for an example.